# Code after readObject() does not run

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am working on a UI which reads serialized object from zookeeper, deserializes it and then converts it into JSON. For some reason I am not able to deseerialize the MQTopic object. But I am able to do the same with other objects.

This is the part which converts the byte[] into the MQTopic object.

```
if (tester != null && tester.contains("com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopic")) {
                System.out.println(getValue());
                ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.value);
                ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
                System.out.println("after deserializing..");
                topic = (MQTopic) is.readObject();
                System.out.println("after typecasting..");
                System.out.println(topic.getTopicName());
                System.out.println(topic.toString());

                is.close();
                in.close();

            }
```

Here **value** is a byte array of the object after serialization.
Nothing runs after `topic = (MQTopic) is.readObject();` . Not even the print statements. The program neither terminates nor an exception is thrown or caught.

**EDIT** : Whole Method

```
public String getStrValue() {
    FtpConnectionInfo ftp = null;
    MQTopic topic = null;
    try {
        String tester = new String(this.value, "UTF-8");
        if (tester != null && tester.contains("FtpConnectionInfo")) {
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.value);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            ftp = (FtpConnectionInfo) is.readObject();
            in.close();
            is.close();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            return gson.toJson(ftp);

        } else if (tester != null
                && tester.contains("com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopic")) {
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.value);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            System.out.println("after deserializing..");
            topic = (MQTopic) is.readObject();
            System.out.println("after typecasting..");
            System.out.println(topic.getTopicName());
            System.out.println(topic.toString());
            is.close();
            in.close();

        } else {
            return new String(this.value, "UTF-8");
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        System.out.println("unsupported error ");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        //logger.error(Arrays.toString(ex.getStackTrace()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in new logic.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("im out of try");

    return null;
}
```

The FTP if loop works fine, but the Topic loop does not work beyond typecasting.

**EDIT 2:** This how the other team stores the object into Zookeeper

```
public static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        os.writeObject(obj);
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
```

The byte[] is stored in Zookeeper and that is what I am retrieving in my UI.

**EDIT 3:** I did a debug of the process and at the point where is is called, these are the values. Can anyone tell me if the object is right ?

[image: is object]

Comment: Is logger enabled in your code? As per your comment, possibly there is an exception on object read.

Comment: There *has* to be an exception throw on that line. The JVM doesn't just stop executing code randomly. Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger to see what actually happens?

Comment: do u mean try catch ? I don't get what you mean by logger.

Comment: @Raniz the whole code is surrounded by a try catch and i'm catching Exception . Still nothing happens.

Comment: Show us your catch block please, @ViChU

Comment: @ArthurEirich just edited with the whole method.

Comment: @Raniz i've added the full method.

Comment: How do you store MQTopic to value, could you show the code that does serialization?

Comment: I don't see any stream closing there.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic The serialization happens in a different code altogether. My part is just to read the objects in the UI. They add the objects the same way for every object. But I am able to read the FTP object but not the Topic object.

Comment: Could you somehow try closing the serialization streams, just to eliminate that possibility? Because it may happen that readObject blocks, waiting for more bytes to come in, but that never happens because there is nobody writing to the stream any longer. And this may be dependent on the object type (longer objects may get flushed automatically), that's why it may work for some objects.

Comment: If that is the case , then I would not be able to retrieve the FTP objects as well. And also after serialization, the byte array is added to the Zookeeper server which runs in my system. Once the object is added, that code is terminated. Anyway will try to ask them to close the resources.and check if it works.

Comment: @Raniz i debugged the code and this is what I get when 'is' is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this wrong. You should deserialize the object first, and then use `instanceof` to see what type it is. Converting binary data to `String` is poor practice at the best of times.

Your actual symptom is not credible. An exception must be thrown, or else you are blocking earlier than stated.

Comment: Yes I know, this is just a prototype and is not the final code. For now, I don't have any problems getting into the loops.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectInputStream's readObject is a blocking method. First check using the [available](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#available--) method if there is something to read without blocking.

available would most probably return 0 in this case.

This might be only half the solution you are looking for, but I think this would let you know if you have anything to read or not.

Comment: I've tried available and it returned 0 for both the objects ie. FTP and Topic. But I still did not have any problem with FTP.

Comment: I see. This means, the byte array has nothing to read from. What is the byte array length (this.value) during the topic deserialization block?

Comment: If that is the case then I suggest you do what @Dragan Bozanovic commented on your question.

Comment: I added the debug info. Can u tell me if you can find anything suspicious in it.

Comment: Can you add os.flush() in the serialize code. I suspect that makes the InputStream assume that there is still more data and it just waits.